# Android: gyroscope sensor data return zero (onSensorChanged())

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope, samsung-galaxy-watch-4

I am creating an application to get accelerometer sensor and gyroscope sensor data from Android Wear(galaxy watch 4)

However, only gyro sensor data returns zero. Could you please solve this problem?
Thank you for any helps.

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   Sensor mAccelerometerSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
   Sensor mGyroscopeSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);

   mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
   mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mGyroscopeSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);


public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

   long now= System.currentTimeMillis();
   if(lastSensed + SAMPLING_PERIOD_MS < now) {

       if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
             //timestamp = event.timestamp;
           accelX = event.values[0];
           accelY = event.values[1];
           accelZ = event.values[2];
       }

       else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE){
           gyroX = event.values[0];
           gyroY = event.values[1];
           gyroZ = event.values[2];
       }
```